# how to get the distance between to points on earth in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, distance, latitude-longitude

i used two methods .. apple's one

```
 @IBAction func getDistancePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    distanceLabel.text = "\(location_2.distanceFromLocation(location_1))m" // Meters

}
```

and mine

```
  @IBAction func getDistancePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let lat1 = location_1.coordinate.latitude
    let lon1 = location_1.coordinate.longitude
    let lat2 = location_2.coordinate.latitude
    let lon2 = location_2.coordinate.longitude


    distanceLabel.text = "\(getDistanceFromLatLonInMeter(lat1, lon1: lon1, lat2: lat2, lon2: lon2))m"

}
func getDistanceFromLatLonInMeter(lat1 : Double ,lon1 : Double ,lat2 : Double ,lon2 : Double) -> Double{


    var earthRadius : Double = 6372797.560856 //inMeter

    var deltaLAT : Double = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1)
    var deltaLON : Double = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1)

    var latitudeH = sin(deltaLAT * 0.5)
    latitudeH *= latitudeH

    var lontitudeH = sin(deltaLON * 0.5)
    lontitudeH *= lontitudeH

    var tmp = cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * cos(deg2rad(lat1));

    return earthRadius * 2.0 * asin(sqrt(latitudeH + tmp*lontitudeH))

}
func deg2rad(deg : Double) -> Double {

    return deg * 0.017453292519943295769236907684886
}
```

Both Are Giving me same value , and Both are Wrong .. when i move my iPhone around (1 meter) it gives me 11 meters , when I move 3 meters it gives me 20 , and so on 
. I don't know where is the problem . what is the correct method to do this thing .how to get the distance??

**for example** --- >

firstLatitude - > 24.4348484485008

firstLongitude - > 39.6552843828735

lastLatitude - > 24.4349537442103

lastLongitude - > 39.6552204902715

it gives the distance - > 13.379 m

it should be 0.7 m (in real)

Comment: The distanceFromLocation method is fine.  If that method and your manual method give the same result, then the input coordinates may be the "problem".  If the coordinates are coming from location services, you can't assume it will always give a precise location with 1-meter accuracy.  Log the actual coordinates.

Comment: I really wouldn't expect your function to be accurate - it assumes a spherical earth, and the earth isn't spherical - you're quoting `earthRadius` to 6 decimal places, but there is no way that the "effective" radius of the earth is anywhere close to that (think kilometres different at higher latitudes) away from the equator. Start here, perhaps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance

Comment: i don't want to go deep I just want to develop a Smart Ruler . is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Those coordinates really are 13.3 meters apart.  The problem must be that you are not getting high-enough accuracy from location services when you move 0.7 meters.

Comment: how can i improve it ?

Comment: Are you using CLLocationManager?  Try these results: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com+ios+cllocationmanager+accuracy&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8  However, you are unlikely to get accuracy less than a few meters and very unlikely to get accuracy less than a meter (consistently).  If your Smart Ruler needs to measure accurately in cm, then CoreLocation probably cannot help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time .. you gave me a lot of informations ..